# App keeps crashing when launching new activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

I'm working on a Simple Android App where I have to link a bunch of pages (or activities) together.

Currently I'm simply trying to tap a button and go to another activity but I'm getting this error in my log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ecelldu.ecellaryabhata, PID: 30310
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.ecelldu.ecellaryabhata/android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2098)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1742)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4590)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4548)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4913)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4881)
        at com.ecelldu.ecellaryabhata.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:17)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6600)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6577)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:781)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25912)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at 

com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30310 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

I'm using Kotlin. Here's my MainActivity.kt code:

```
package com.ecelldu.ecellaryabhata

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.content.Intent
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button_about.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, activity_about::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.ecelldu.ecellaryabhata">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".about">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As you can see, I have included the second activity in the Manifest but for some reason I think it isn't visible and hence the ActivityNotFound exception.

Just in case, here's about.kt:

```
package com.ecelldu.ecellaryabhata

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class about : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about)
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find what's wrong in my coding. There are no compile time issues popping up whatsoever.
How can I resolve this and get to my other activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies not in the linking but in ID allotment.

The button in activity_main.xml that I was using to link to activity_about.xml had the ID `about`.

Also, there was a mistake in one line in the MainActivity.kt

`val intent = Intent(this, about::class.java)`

This was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`val intent = Intent(this, about::class.java)`